# How to send item id to server via ajax : jquery sortable

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a group of image that need to re-arrange. So I put the image inside its div. I can replace it but it's not send the id via ajax.

**html**

```
<div class="row sortable">
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="1">
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/200x150" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4" id="2">
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/200x150" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4" id="3">
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/200x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('.sortable').sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {
    $.ajax({
      data: $(this).sortable('serialize'),
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/echo/json/', 
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

here is my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bmp6xoog/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation clearly states that

> It works by default by looking at the id of each item in the format
>   `"setname_number"`, and it spits out a hash like 
>   `"setname[]=number&setname[]=number"`.
>
> Note: If serialize returns an empty string, **make sure the id
>   attributes include an underscore. They must be in the form:
>   `"set_number"`**.
>   For example, a 3 element list with id attributes `"foo_1"`,
>   `"foo_5"`, `"foo_2"` will serialize to `"foo[]=1&foo[]=5&foo[]=2"`.
>   You can
>   use an underscore, equal sign or hyphen to separate the set and
>   number.
>   For example `"foo=1"`, `"foo-1"`, and `"foo_1"` all serialize to
>   `"foo[]=1"`.

You're using ID's with just numbers, which is why it's not working, it has to be an ID in the format `foo_1` etc.

```js
$('.sortable').sortable({
  update: function(event, ui) {
    console.log( $(this).sortable('serialize') ); // works
    
    $.ajax({
      data: $(this).sortable('serialize'),
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/echo/json/', 
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div class="row sortable">
  <div class="col-sm-4" id="item_1"> <!-- like this -->
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/200x150" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4" id="item_2"> <!-- and this -->
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/200x150" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4" id="item_3"> <!-- and this -->
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/200x150" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to serialize the list you must have a underscore on the id of the elements, like this id="id_3"